# How to open WSL-Installed apps on Windows 10

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux-tools

I've recently started with WSL in multiple oses (mainly Ubuntu and Kali Linux). I have tried installing a few apps in WSL but don't know how to open them. Also, Kali Linux has some pre-installed apps like bully which are helpful in hacking. Is there any way to find and open those pre-installed apps and/or the apps I installed using `sudo apt-get install <Package name>`?

Comment: If you are asking about opening them as a Graphical app, try https://github.com/microsoft/wslg

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I don't think any of those are duplicates for this question since the answer is going to be different for WSL.  However, I can't really vote to reopen the question since it still "Needs focus". Each application is different. You should ask about *one* application (or a related class of application) per question. Thanks!